Copying certain named file to its related numbered folder
I have made a number of files with names like 98745.jpg ,98746.jpg, 98747.jpg.This number represents the names with 98745=anna, 98746=nuuk, 98747=nissum. So i want to copy those numbered files to the folders with name related to the number. This is just an example. I have nearly 400 to 500 files with such numbers. How can i do this using batch script.?

"400 to 500 files": all in the same directory? With each (different) number associated to a specific name? Where and how is the file containing the associations stored (I'm assuming you kept track of those in a file? Please provide an example of the file)? Are the target directories (anna, nuuk, nissum etc) already present in the files' directory? Or should they be created? If so, where? Please edit your question adding this information.

SMOP! (Simple Matter Of Programming), if you use simple Linux tools. After reading man find xargs mv, do something like the following Untested code:
mkdir anna nuik nissum
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '98745*.jpg' -print0 | \
    xargs -0 -r mv -t anna
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '98746*.jpg' -print0 | \
    xargs -0 -r mv -t nuuk
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '98747*.jpg' -print0 | \
    xargs -0 -r mv -t nissum

See, it's easy.

What in the question makes you think they would have more than one file starting with the same number for each name? Judging by what's written, it appears instead that they have to deal with 400 to 500 files, each with a different number and each belonging to a different person (by the way, find has -exec, which can save both the pipe and the need of juggling filenames containing whitespace: find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '98745*.jpg' -exec mv -t anna {} +). ARG_MAX-safe considering the number of files.
